# Rabbi David M. Feldman,Orthodox?

Tags: rabbis

I own a book on birth control written by Rabbi David M Feldman. I was very impressed on how much bikius he has and erudition on the subject. I really cannot find any info on him,and wanted to know of he was an Orthodox or Conservitive Rabbi. From his writing I got the impression that he was orthodox,but I am not sure.

Comment: http://menachemmendel.net/blog/passing-of-rabbi-david-feldman/ That's him. Definitely a first-rate scholar. IIRC his Shul didn't have a Mechitza (or at least not an at all tall one) but he quit from JTS to protest something (ordaining women rabbis? something like that). His son R Daniel Z Feldman is a Rosh Yeshiva at YU. Incidentally, I believe he's a Rabbi Dr.

Comment: thanks for info,so is it safe to assume that he was orthodox? was he similiar to  Saul Liberman ?

Comment: I believe that Rabbi  Saul Lieberman specifically had a mechitza when he prayed.

Comment: @sabbahillel I think the discussion of whether he was "Orthodox" or "Conservative" isn't worthwhile or productive here as it dismisses any nuance that may exist between them. If you want to say his mechitza was too short so we should dismiss everything he wrote as Conservative nonsense, you'd be doing yourself a great disservice. Things aren't always black and white.

Comment: The Jewish Center of Teaneck (jcot.org) claims to be "Modern Orthodox" if that is the same place. It does not give a history or mention Rabbi Feldman on the current web site.

Comment: @DoubleAA I did not say anything about whether he was or was not "Orthodox" or  "Conservative" I had been pointing out that there are those who seem to fall in between based on practice rather than affiliation.

Comment: I know you don't have to rely on me, but he was Orthodox, and a great man.

Comment: @sabbahillel I think it's the same Shul but they've had a new rabbi come in and raise the mechitzas and such. They may have affiliated differently back then.

Comment: @DoubleAA OK thanks. then the web site would not answer the question.

Comment: no one is doubting he was a great man ,and an obvious talmid chacham,but it seems like he was affiliated with the conservative movement and was wondering what his personal stance was. I would like to rely on you ,but a source is necessary .

Comment: @shmu and I'd be hesitant to rely on plenty of orthodox rabbis for psak too. Its got nothing to do with the movement.

Comment: @sabbahillel It [used to be a Conservative synagogue](http://www.northjersey.com/community-news/community-events-and-announcements/center-to-soon-be-an-orthodox-synagogue-1.210065) during Rabbi Feldman's tenure (it was Conservative, but relatively traditional).

Comment: [New York Times profile](http://www.nytimes.com/1984/01/01/nyregion/rabbi-s-challenge.html) from 1984. [Eulogy](http://jewishstandard.timesofisrael.com/a-time-to-mourn/) in the Jewish Standard.

Comment: @sam knowing the guy and knowing the family, I would rely on him. I won't represent what his personal stance on things was, but if you have a particular question, I can pass it along.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Not definitely. RMF is writing polemic. In some ways I can imagine preferring someone who is open about his identity instead of pretending they are still Orthodox.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.northjersey.com/community-news/community-events-and-announcements/center-to-soon-be-an-orthodox-synagogue-1.210065) article says Rabbi Dr. David M. Feldman was **a leader of the Conservative movement's traditional faction**.

> The JCT maintained itself as an ultra-traditional synagogue under both Rabbi Washer's leadership and that of his successor, Rabbi Dr. David M. Feldman. **Though ordained by the Jewish Theological Seminary and a leader of the Conservative movement's traditional faction, Rabbi Feldman also holds an Orthodox ordination.** As Teaneck developed into a growing Orthodox community and children moving elsewhere the JCT's once robust membership of nearly 1,500 families began to dwindle. Its model of conservative Judaism no longer had an audience.

Comment: At this point, I believe it's spelled Traditional, with a capital "T."  Rabbi Aaron Soloveichik was quick to correct someone who referred to a Traditional synagogue as Conservative.

Comment: I simply copied & pasted. (Twice). Never heard of this person and am unfamiliar with nuances of non-Orthodox Yiddishkeit.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.jpost.com/Opinion/Remembering-Rabbi-Dr-David-M-Feldman-bioethicist-and-mensch-383930) states that he received his rabbinical ordination (semicha) from Yeshiva University. Most who do this are Orthodox, but it is not a 100% guarantee. The article does not offer any details either way.

Comment: Interesting. Other articles state his undergraduate degree was from YU and that he received ordination at the Conservative JTS, where one of his close teachers was [Rabbi Saul Lieberman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Lieberman#Paradox_in_Affiliation).

Comment: @Fred Several rabbis received double semicha. The rabbi of my shul has semicha from both JTS and YU, if I'm correct. I don't know how common this is, but it's not unusual, either. It seems these people do this for political purposes and career advancement. My rabbi is Orthodox but the congregation is Conservative / traditional (meaning that other than lacking a mechitza and using a Tzomet microphone on Shabbat (which is  permissible according to some opinions), is similar to Orthodox.

Comment: Interesting. I know that it was very common back in the 50's and 60's for Orthodox-affiliated synagogues to be more or less like that (usually to the chagrin of their rabbi, though).

Comment: @Fred "(usually to the chagrin of their rabbi, though)" - Congregational rabbis, inevitably, are "slaves" to the board members that decide on their salaries.